# pgrouting pointAtoB function

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

Has anyone successfully implemented [pgr_fromAtoB](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html#route-between-lat-lon-points-and-return-ordered-geometry-with-heading) function?

Sometimes I get 0 results from points in the same line string, sometimes I do get results,

How can accuracy be improved?, or maybe do I need to normalize my data?